# local server xampp not updating my webpages

Tags: xampp, localhost

I am working on a website in php by using xampp as a local server. Problem is that when a write some code in my **css,js,php** files there are not updating in browser I am using **google chrome and firefox** but the problem is same on both browsers. I'm using sublime and Atome my text editors.

Below is screenshot of my text editor and browser which code is display in editor that same code is not showing in browser inspect area

Code is:

[image]

Inspect Element:

[image]

Comment: When I look at the two images I can't see any different. Could give an example which code you would expect in your browser?

Comment: look at photo one there is php code in star

Comment: but in phot 2 there is html code is in start

Comment: i want php code in my browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PHP code (which is present in your editor but not in your web browser) is **never sent to the browser**! PHP is a script language for the server side and executed on the server.

This means that PHP is interpreted and executed by a PHP interpreter.

Let's make an example:

```
<b><?php echo "Hello"; ?></b>
```

This PHP code would produce the following HTML output (which is visible to your web browser):

```
<b>Hello</b>
```